# Logo not showing up in menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In my WordPress menu, I have a logo that is set as the first list item. It is showing up fine on home page, but on all other pages it does not show up. This is because the url for the image is different on home page than all other pages. Look at pictures for better understanding. [what I currently have the url set to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjrF0.png) [Url on pages other than home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFm60.jpg)
As you can see, on pages other than homepage, the correct url should have the page slug. I'm not sure how to go about putting the slug into the current url on my menu. Thanks in advance!

```
    <?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package Revived_Furnishings
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'revivedfurnishings' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">

        <img class="mobile-logo" src="wp-content/themes/revivedfurnishings/images/logo.jpg">

            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( '', 'revivedfurnishings' ); ?>Menu</button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would put a logo in as a menu item. It would be better to put it directly in your header.php file. However if you are not accustomed with editing wordpress themes then all you have to do is add a `/` at the beginning of your image src. This means the URL src will be treated as a root path and won't be appended to the end of the current pages URL.

```
<img class="logo" src="/wp-content/themes/revivedfurnishings/images/logo.jpg">
```

UPDATE:
This should allow you to add a logo to your header navigation. What I am doing here is adding the `'container' => false` argument to the `wp_nav_menu` function so it does not include the `<ul></ul>` wrapper. You can then add your own `<ul></ul>` wrapper and add your own link/img.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/"><img class="logo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); >/wp-content/themes/revivedfurnishings/images/logo.jpg"></a></li>
<?php wp_nav_menu( 
  array( 
    'theme_location' => 'menu-1', 
    'menu_id' => 'primary-menu', 
    'container' => false 
  ) 
); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't seem to work. It's still looking for URL with the page slug. I wanted to put it directly into header.php, but I was having difficulty understanding where to add in the new <li>. I will post my header.php code for you to see. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnChristensen I have updated my answer, with an explanation as to how you would add the logo to your nav in your header.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you sholud give image path like that:

`<img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/image_folder_name/image.jpg" alt="image" />`

There is not need to mention "wp-content/themes/revivedfurnishings"